# In php validating a .csv file the last column is never null, except the last line. How to check the linebreak

Tags: php, validation, csv

Hi I have this problem.

I have a .csv that I want to validate, non of the variables can be null.

If my .csv is

```
A;ABC;
A;A;
A;A;
A;A;
```

And the php that read this file looks like:

```
$fd = fopen("uploads/".$nombreArchivo,"r");
        while (!feof($fd)){
                $lineTexto++;
                $reg = fgets($fd);
                $arreglo = explode(";", $reg);
                if(count($arreglo)==3){
                    if(!$arreglo[2]){
                        $_SESSION["info"]=$_SESSION["info"]."The cell 3 of the line $lineTexto can not be null<br/>";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $_SESSION["info"]=$_SESSION["info"]."Número de líneas incorrectos en la linea $lineTexto<br/>";
                }
            }
```

The result is

**The cell 3 of the line 4 can not be null**

What about all the other lines that have a linebreak, but they are null?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you checked to see what's in the third cell on the first three lines? If you don't remove the linebreaks, they could be in there still.

Comment: Well I want to check that third cell, but do not know how when there is a linebreaks.

Comment: Try something like `echo "*" . $arreglo[2] . "*"` - that will show you the contents of the cell, with an asterisk either side. If there's a linebreak in there, the asterisks will be on separate lines.

Comment: Well I have done that and it looks like there is an space. * * in the first lines but the last line there is no space **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not null .. the issue is that they contain empty space and you can resolve this by using `trim`

```
    if (count($arreglo) == 3) {
        $arreglo[2] = trim($arreglo[2]);
        if (! $arreglo[2]) {
            echo "The cell 3 of the line $lineTexto can not be null<br/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Número de líneas incorrectos en la linea $lineTexto<br/>";
    }
```

Example Output

```
The cell 3 of the line 1 can not be null
The cell 3 of the line 2 can not be null
The cell 3 of the line 3 can not be null
The cell 3 of the line 4 can not be null
```